# OpenSSL 3.0 generating p12 certificate issue with FIPS

Tags: openssl, certificate, fips-140-2, rhel9

I am running the OpenSSL command to generate bundle.p12 with -legacy option. RHEL 9 FIPS Enabled setup.

```
  openssl pkcs12 -export -legacy -in cacert.pem -inkey cakey.pem -out bundle.p12
```

```
Error creating PKCS12 structure for bundle.p12
80C4B9FD5E7F0000:error:0308010C:digital envelope routines:inner_evp_generic_fetch:unsupported:crypto/evp/evp_fetch.c:349:Global default library context, Algorithm (RC2-40-CBC : 187), Properties ()
80C4B9FD5E7F0000:error:11800067:PKCS12 routines:PKCS12_item_i2d_encrypt_ex:encrypt error:crypto/pkcs12/p12_decr.c:191:
80C4B9FD5E7F0000:error:11800067:PKCS12 routines:PKCS12_pack_p7encdata_ex:encrypt error:crypto/pkcs12/p12_add.c:127:
```

How can I resolve this issue in RHEL 9 FIPS environment?

Comment: Isn't that exactly what FIPS 140-2 mode is _supposed to do_?

Answer (score 0):

before using legacy flag for openssl 3 you need to enable legacy support in openssl.cnf
https://www.practicalnetworking.net/practical-tls/openssl-3-and-legacy-providers/